# ts(2322) Error in code when working with React.FC = () => {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript

the code below give me the following error: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)

Here is the code:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const Dashboard: FC = () => {
    <div>

    </div>
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I've seen similar code that did not produce this error.  Can someone please help?
Thanks,
Sean

Comment: if you want to return smth from arraw function you have two options: use curly braces along with `return` keyword or get rid of curly braces and return an expression. Example: `const Dashboard: FC = () =></div>` or `const Dashboard: FC = () =>{ return </div> }`

Comment: Arrow function docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @captain-yossarian when I submitted the original question some code was missing

Comment: The function doesn't return anything at the moment, it can't pretend it's a React component.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `block` syntax, you need to specify the return keyword. Learn more about [arrow-function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-arrow-function/)

Try this way.

Example

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const Dashboard: FC = () => {

  return(
      <div>
       Something...
      </div>
    )
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Or

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const Dashboard: FC = () =>  <div> Something... </div>

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add return keyword since "FC" requires an html element to be returned.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

const Dashboard: FC = () => {
   return ( 
   <div>

    </div>
    )
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of `FC` type:

```js
   type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

As you probably might have noticed, `FC` is an alias for `FunctionComponent` which in turn is a function with several static properties:  `propTypes`, `contextTypes` ...

This function `(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;` returns wither `ReactElement<any,any>` or `null`

This is a definition of `ReactElement`:

```js
    interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }
```

Consider `ReactElement` as `jsx` element.

Hence, `FC` expects you to return either `null` or `jsx` element.

`Dashboard` is an arrow function. It means it can return an expression without `return` keyword. But under one circumstance  - expression should be right after `=>` symbol.

Please see [arrow function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It means that you need to do this:

```js
const Dashboard: FC = () => <div></div>
```